# Angular routes not working with many modules

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm creating my first application in Angular 4 and I imported my AppRoutingModule into app.module.ts, as far as I know, by importing the module into this app.module it becomes "visible" to the rest of the application. From this principle, I did not declare in a module below (retaguarda.module), but the component retaguarda.component has in its html the `<router-outlet> </ router-outlet>` tag, the error shown asks to import the AppRoutingModule Inside rearModule, however, as stated above, being declared in the app.module, should not be visible to the rear. Module as well?

Declaring straight in the retaguardamodule the error disappears, however the navigation is with bug, so I believe that the problem is in more than one place. Can you help me with that, too?

app.module.ts:

```
...
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,

        AppRoutingModule,
        RetaguardaModule,
        LoginModule
      ],
      providers: [
        LoginGuard,
        LoginService,
        Ambiente
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

retaguarda.module.ts:

```
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NavbarModule,
    SidenavModule,
    CadastrosModule,
    MovimentacoesModule,
    AdministracaoModule,
    RelatoriosModule,
    ConfiguracoesModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    RetaguardaComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RetaguardaComponent
  ]
})
export class RetaguardaModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-retaguarda></app-retaguarda>
```

retaguarda.component.html:

```
<header>
    <app-navbar *ngIf="ambiente.usuarioLogado"></app-navbar>
    <app-sidenav ></app-sidenav>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the error (which you did not supply in your question) closely you will see that it does not ask you in import `AppRoutingModule` at all but rather the [`RouterModule`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html). The reason being that your `AppModule` is presently the only one doing so and only it's "contained" components are aware of the `router-outlet` declaration. I'd suggest getting more acquainted with the router in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.forRoot()` and `.forChild()` here.

Start with AppRoutingModule.forRoot() and having a single route give you your `RetaguardaComponent`.  Next, have the `RetaguardaModule` use the `.forChild()` notation to route within your module.

If `RetaguardaComponent` doesn't have any child routes and isn't a route itself (i.e. it always displays), then consider putting it into a `CoreModule` and having the AppComponent handle the routing.

Read more from this page to get a better grasp on how to set up routing:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#why-routing-module

Comment: I will read, but appModule should be my core, right? The "retaguarda" would be the name of one of the applications. Everything was working when I declared the modules all within the appModule, but I did this refactoring to leave each module within its parent module. All these modules: CadastrosModule, MovimentacoesModule, AdministracaoModule,RelatoriosModule, ConfiguracoesModule, DashboardModule are children of the RetaguardaModule.

Comment: They actually recommend a separate `CoreModule` for keeping singular (or non-routed) components in one place together.  This link might help: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: It almost sounds like your `Retaguarda` is really just more of your `AppModule` and they should not be separated.